# Finding sessions associated with an IP address using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, ip-address

[Originally Posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692931/pdo-stmt-is-this-how-it-should-be-done)

First of all I want to say that I'm new to PDO. I did tried it once but since I found the oop solution complicated and even impossible (`SELECT * FROM table_name`) I decided to use PDO.

But I'm not sure if I do it right, so I'd like to take criticism about what I've done. I'm "translating" the mysqli stmt to pdo. Here's an example from one thing I've "translated":

```
// Client IP has been defined previously,
// But for the example:
$ip     = '3ffe:1900:4545:3:200:f8ff:fe21:67cf';
$sql_ip = inet_pton($ip); // IPV6

try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE s_ipv4 = :s_ipv4 OR s_ipv6 = :s_ipv6');
    $stmt->bindParam(':s_ipv4', $sql_ip);
    $stmt->bindParam(':s_ipv6', $sql_ip);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() === 0) {
        // No rows
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    die ($exception->getMessage());
}

unset($stmt);
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, and thank you for declaring your cross post. Please fill in the "do something" placeholders so that we can review this code properly. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main points of improvement:

1. First of all, never ever use `die(error message)` in your scripts. Neither try/catch should be ever used only to echo the error message out. You'd be surprised, but you will have **more informative error message** if just get rid of the whole try/catch/die stuff. Please read my article on [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) for the details
2. PDO code itself could be made more tidy, thanks to various helper functions PDO offers

So the whole code should be

```
$sql_ip = inet_pton($ip); // IPV6

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE s_ipv4 = ? OR s_ipv6 = ?');
$stmt->execute([$sql_ip,$sql_ip]);

if ($stmt->fetchColumn()) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // No rows
}
```

Here I used positional placeholders for brevity, and sent your variables directly to execute for the same purpose.

Also I recommend to avoid `rowCount()` function as it would be more logical: in your code you are selecting some data, but never use it. Instead, I would suggest to use the actual data selected (just a literal "1" in your case, fetched directly using `fetchColumn()` method).